# how to convert the date and time format in excel to simple and sortable format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am facing issue with date/time format **Tue Oct 02 19:59:38 CDT 2018** to convert this in simple format like **MM-DD-YYYY HH:ss** so I can sort out in ascending or descending order in Excel. Right now, the issue with time format **Tue Oct 02 19:59:38 CDT 2018** is I cannot be able to do any ascending or descending operations or sorting based on date and time. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You are gong to need a helper column that parses that string into a date form recognized by Excel.

Comment: If you have TEXTSPLIT: `=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),{3,2,6,4}))`

Comment: Or this way: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(A1,{9,5,25,12},{2,3,4,8}))+0`

Comment: @karthik let me add this as an answer, to close the post

Answer (score 1):

> Posting the solutions as an answer since OP confirmed its working,
> hence to close the post.

[image]

---

One can use `TEXTSPLIT()` as mentioned by **[SCOTT CRANER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, if using **MS365**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),{3,2,6,4}))
```

---

However, if one do not have access to `TEXTSPLIT()` then using `TEXTJOIN()` & `MID()`

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(A3,{9,5,25,12},{2,3,4,8}))+0
```